# for looping list that's immutable/returning the modified one?

Tags: python

while I was watching pycon video, I got so confused. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns

```
num = [1,2,3]
for x in num:
    x=x*3
print(num)
```

this prints 1,2,3

```
new_list=[]
for x in range(len(num))
new_list = x[num]*3 + new_list[]
```

I want 3,6,9

Comment: The first snippet basically does nothing. The second is invalid syntax.

Comment: @AndrewLi can you explain why?

Comment: Because you're modifying a copy of each element which is thrown away after each iteration? Modifying the item in a `for-in` does not at all change the original list because the item is a copy of the current element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = [1,2,3]
for i in range(len(num)):
    num[i] = num[i] * 3
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a list with step size 3 directly, using range:

```
first = 3
num_elements = 3
step = 3

nums = range(first, first + step*num_elements, step) # Python2
# nums = list(range(first, first + step*num_elements, step)) # Python3
```

or, more terse,
    nums = range(3, 12, 3) # Python2
    # nums = list(range(3, 12, 3)) # Python3

Alternatively you can use list comprehension, if your list is already given

```
initial = [1,2,3]
nums = [3*elem for elem in initial]
```